# incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression | void is not a functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, consumer, functional-interface

I am going through Java 8 Feature and using Jshell to explore it. I tried to run the below command:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = (str)->System.out::println;
```

But it failed with the below error:

```
Error:
|  incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
|      void is not a functional interface
```

I didn't get exactly what's the issue Consumer takes one argument and return nothing. Same I am doing here by passing 1 arg str and printing. So what's the issue with this syntax.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a `Consumer<String>` that prints the string given to it, it's either a lambda expression calling `System.out::println`:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = (str)->System.out.println(str);
```

or a method reference to `System.out::println`

```
Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
```

but not *both*. You seem to have mixed up the syntax. `str -> System.out::println` would be a lambda expression that takes in an object, ignores it, and returns a method reference to `System.out::println`. You can for example do:

```
Function<Object, Consumer<String>> func = str -> System.out::println;
```

but such indirectness is very uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing lambda expression with method references.

If you want to use a lambda expression,

```
Consumer<String> consumer = str -> System.out.println(str);
```

If you want a method reference,

```
Consumer<String> consumer = System.out::println;
```